# Write to stream / finalyze in Dispose method

Tags: .net, idisposable

I have class which writes header of the file in constructor. Then user calls method which writes chunks of data to the stream. And then in Dispose I'm writing tail data.

I don't want to extract any specific method which will do it - because it will break encapsulation and users always forget to call it. Using "using" construct is much preferred.

I wonder if this conceptually correct to write anything in Dispose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's correct. Many classes in the framework act as such. For instance `FileStream` will flush its buffer on `Dispose`, which will write to the file. Same for `BufferedStream`, `StreamWriter` etc.

Just don't confuse `Dispose` with `Finalize` (finalizer, aka `~YourClass`) - it's not the same thing, and relying on this one would be a *very bad thing*™.

Comment: Looks like understand what conceptual issue I may have - Dispose should not throw exceptions. And if I have sophisticated code - it may be painful to track exceptions on Dispose.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid exceptions in `Dispose`, for the same reason you should avoid them in a `finally` block: they can mask an actual exception in the `try` part. Sometimes it's unavoidable though (I/O error on the closing write for instance).

Comment: Don't you have any sample / or design name in mind that does write some final data after user done something to class state?

Comment: Well... Take a look at [`StreamWriter.Dispose()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f922405b11eca536,references) for instance. Writing final data is a very common use case for the `Dispose` pattern usage.